# Android Studio...passing a query value to an internet search in an intent

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The following code is used with an onClickListener to open YouTube, and SHOULD pass the query value.

```
        String Query = MOVENAME.toString();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/#q=" );
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.putExtra("query", Query ); 
        startActivity(intent);
        try {
            this.startActivity(intent);
        } catch
```

However, it ONLY opens YouTube... BUT IF I replace it with...

```
intent.putExtra("query", "anything I want to search for" ); <-note text surrounded by " "
```

THEN it DOES run a search based on the text entered.

Any suggestions on how to pass the EditText info stored in MOVENAME to the intent in a format that will work?

Comment: Well what's `MOVENAME.toString()`? Also I would recommend taking a look at the recommended naming conventions, it makes your code a lot more readable.

Answer (score 0):

correction.... String Query = MOVENAME.getText().toString();

had neglected the .getText()  required and was passing the object not the contents.